# Summary report for contacts with and without emails

Tags: reporting

The requirement is to create a summary report group by emails - but it is not just based on emails - it is based on whether the email field is empty or not. Is there any declarative way of doing that? We are trying to avoid coding.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved - I just need to add a formula field to track whether the email field is blank or not.